# Recurrence that contains Sum of previous elements

Tags: recursion

I would like to create the recurrence that contains the summation of all previous elements, but it seems it does not work. That I'm doing wrong?

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[n] == Sum[a[k], {k, 1, n - 1}], a[1] == 1, a[2] == 1}, a, {n, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use `Nest[Append[#, Total[#]] &, {1, 1}, 10]`...

Comment: The documentation states that "The eqns can involve objects of the form a[n+i] where i is any fixed integer." but you using `a[k]` which is not allowed.